# django and dropzone how to post form

Tags: python, html, django, forms, dropzone.js

I have gone through django and dropzone. I have implemented drag and drop feature of dropzone in django.
My template look like:

```
<form id="add-multiple" class="dropzone" action="{% url "name_add" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
    <button id="submit-all" type="submit" value="Submit" form="add-multiple">
        Submit all files
    </button>

    <script src="{% static 'js/dropzone.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {

            // Prevents Dropzone from uploading dropped files immediately
            autoProcessQueue : false,
            paramName: "files",

            init : function() {
                var submitButton = document.querySelector("#submit-all")
                myDropzone = this;

                submitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
                    myDropzone.processQueue();
                    // Tell Dropzone to process all queued files.
                });

                // You might want to show the submit button only when
                // files are dropped here:
                this.on("addedfile", function() {
                    // Show submit button here and/or inform user to click it.
                });

            }
        };
    </script>
```

Here, I am getting the css and uploading perfectly, but when I submit the form, it doesn't call the `{% url "name_add" %}` url. I mean, the form is not posted and it doesn't call that url.

I followed this tutorial https://amatellanes.wordpress.com/2013/11/05/dropzonejs-django-how-to-build-a-file-upload-form/ to achieve this.

First thing, my form is not being posted or it says it is not calling the url in form action. Second there is not any use of my form that I have created in forms.py to upload a file. In the tutorial also there is no use of form. Why is that and without form how form can be submitted  because view requires form.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you message me and show me the view you use to process that form?  I can't get the file upload, or multiple file upload to work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in:

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
....
```

actually `myDropzone` is the camelized version of the HTML element's ID.

so the form **id** must be `my_dropzone` instead of `add-multiple`:

```
<form id="my_dropzone" class="dropzone" action...
```